# JS function used globally in multiple files

Tags: javascript

The title was kind of hard to write correctly, so I hope I can explain this well enough.

I have a function defined in the main function of my application...

```
let renderTemplate = (req, res, view, model) => {
  res.render('template',
             {
               'view': view,     
               'model': model 
             });
}
```

And then I use it in multiple, small controller-esque files, like so

```
let foo = (req, res) => {
   renderTemplate(req, res, 'index', {});
}
```

The question is: How do I include `renderTemplate` in all of my controller-esque classes without placing it in or injecting the code per file?

Comment: what are you using for module/package management?

Comment: @DanielA.White As of right now, my own method that iterates over all the controllers and adds their functions to an object, which in turn gets returned to the main.

Comment: why don't you just use a module if you are just using node?

Comment: @DanielA.White Is there a specific Node module that could handle the injection for me? I could probably write the injection myself in this case (hence, no module needed), but I'd rather know if there's a cleaner solution than injecting the function per file.

Comment: just do `module.exports = renderTemplate`

Comment: @DanielA.White That still doesn't completely solve the problem. Each GET and POST request for the pages on my server have their own individual files that define the behavior. So, a file called `index.js` handles all GET and POST request behavior for requests to the index page. The problem is, if I want to keep this design, then the `renderTemplate` method either has to be `require`'d per file or injected at run-time into each file before I individually `require` them.